# 1099r IRS form in Crystal Report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

we need to generate 1099r IRS report from the application and we have decided to develop this with crystal reports. i am just curious to know that anyone did this crystal report and if so, could somebody pass your report templates.

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache:vzIPLclgiugJ:www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1099r.pdf+1099r&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi_V1uhhAofGA1bES1NXmdvcgEXirIr5Cjff3kfMcrgMA5wSO4HleX6gqWRl1ebu7Be9d4_diXQxPxCTX2pEnPg76ifbVOf47HYSK3fSgIPbpWwCYXBYZU_S0fwnCkXOWeGAnLd&sig=AFQjCNFaorojNLilm8WgbmWl66_aJU-5Wg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a report that added data to an infection-control form.  I found the form online, made an image of it, inserted it into the report, then placed database fields over the respective form fields.  You may want to have multiple Detail sections to segment and size the pages.